# Quickest way to merge two very large pandas dataframes using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, merge

I have multiple sets of very large csv files that I need to merge based on a unique ID. This unique ID I set as the index which is based on a concatenation my Origin and Destination columns.

**Dataframe 1**:

|  | Origin | Destination | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 70478 | 70 | 478 | 0.002779 |
| 70479 | 70 | 479 | 0.001673 |
| 70480 | 70 | 480 | 0.000427 |
| 70481 | 70 | 481 | 0.001503 |
| 70482 | 70 | 482 | 0.01215 |
| 70483 | 70 | 483 | 0.004507 |
| 70484 | 70 | 484 | 0.001871 |
| 70485 | 70 | 485 | 0.006522 |
| 70486 | 70 | 486 | 0.004786 |
| 70487 | 70 | 487 | 0.026566 |

**Dataframe 2**:

|  | Origin | Destination | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 70478 | 70 | 478 | 135.974365 |
| 70479 | 70 | 479 | 130.936752 |
| 70480 | 70 | 480 | 111.191734 |
| 70481 | 70 | 481 | 98.170746 |
| 70482 | 70 | 482 | 88.257645 |
| 70483 | 70 | 483 | 102.095566 |
| 70484 | 70 | 484 | 103.585373 |
| 70485 | 70 | 485 | 114.298431 |
| 70486 | 70 | 486 | 97.331055 |
| 70487 | 70 | 487 | 85.754776 |

My **final table** should be as follows (Demand = Value from df1; Time = Value from df2; Demand_Time = Time/Demand):

|  | Origin | Destination | Demand | Time | Demand_Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 70 | 478 | 0.002779 | 135.974365 | 0.377858 |
| 1 | 70 | 479 | 0.001673 | 130.936752 | 0.219041 |
| 2 | 70 | 480 | 0.000427 | 111.191734 | 0.047494 |
| 3 | 70 | 481 | 0.001503 | 98.170746 | 0.147536 |
| 4 | 70 | 482 | 0.01215 | 88.257645 | 1.072321 |
| 5 | 70 | 483 | 0.004507 | 102.095566 | 0.460115 |
| 6 | 70 | 484 | 0.001871 | 103.585373 | 0.193806 |
| 7 | 70 | 485 | 0.006522 | 114.298431 | 0.74551 |
| 8 | 70 | 486 | 0.004786 | 97.331055 | 0.465854 |
| 9 | 70 | 487 | 0.026566 | 85.754776 | 2.278125 |

I do a `.compare` between df1 and df2 which produces the following new dataframe:

|  | Origin |  | Destination |  | Value |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | self | other | self | other | self | other |
| 70478 | 70 | 70 | 478 | 478 | 0.002779 | 135.974365 |
| 70479 | 70 | 70 | 479 | 479 | 0.001673 | 130.936752 |
| 70480 | 70 | 70 | 480 | 480 | 0.000427 | 111.191734 |
| 70481 | 70 | 70 | 481 | 481 | 0.001503 | 98.170746 |
| 70482 | 70 | 70 | 482 | 482 | 0.01215 | 88.257645 |
| 70483 | 70 | 70 | 483 | 483 | 0.004507 | 102.095566 |
| 70484 | 70 | 70 | 484 | 484 | 0.001871 | 103.585373 |
| 70485 | 70 | 70 | 485 | 485 | 0.006522 | 114.298431 |
| 70486 | 70 | 70 | 486 | 486 | 0.004786 | 97.331055 |
| 70487 | 70 | 70 | 487 | 487 | 0.026566 | 85.754776 |

I then create a new final `pd.DataFrame` df, iterate over my compare table above and `.append` to my final new df.

The last part that iterates and appends takes a very long time on very large tables (a few hundred thousand records each) - about 1.5 hours each time.

Is there a way to do this last part more efficiently?

Thank you.

**Code sample**:

```
import pandas as pd

# Replicating sample df1 (.read_csv from csv file 1)
df_1_data = [[70, 478, 0.0027788935694843],
             [70, 479, 0.0016728754853829],
             [70, 480, 0.0004271405050531],
             [70, 481, 0.0015028485795482],
             [70, 482, 0.0121498983353376],
             [70, 483, 0.0045067127794027],
             [70, 484, 0.0018709792057052],
             [70, 485, 0.0065224897116422],
             [70, 486, 0.0047862790524959],
             [70, 487, 0.0265655759721994]]
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(df_1_data, columns=['Origin', 'Destination', 'Value'])
df_1 = df_1.set_index(df_1['Origin'].astype(str) + df_1['Destination'].astype(str))
print(df_1)

# Replicating sample df2 (.read_csv from csv file 2)
df_2_data = [[70, 478, 135.9743652],
             [70, 479, 130.9367523],
             [70, 480, 111.1917343],
             [70, 481, 98.17074585],
             [70, 482, 88.25764465],
             [70, 483, 102.0955658],
             [70, 484, 103.5853729],
             [70, 485, 114.2984314],
             [70, 486, 97.33105469],
             [70, 487, 85.754776]]
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df_2_data, columns=['Origin', 'Destination', 'Value'])
df_2 = df_2.set_index(df_2['Origin'].astype(str) + df_2['Destination'].astype(str))
print(df_2)

df_compare = df_1.compare(df_2, keep_shape=True, keep_equal=True)
print(df_compare)

df_out = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Origin', 'Destination', 'Demand', 'Time', 'Demand_Time'])
for index, row in df_compare.iterrows():
    df_out = df_out.append({'Origin': int(row['Origin']['self']), 'Destination': int(row['Destination']['self']),
                            'Demand': row['Value']['self'], 'Time': row['Value']['other'],
                            'Demand_Time': row['Value']['self'] * row['Value']['other']}, ignore_index=True)
print(df_out)

print('\nCOMPLETED')
```

Comment: Your output is not `Demand_Time = Time/Demand` but `Demand_Time = Time*Demand`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
out = (df1.rename(columns={'Value': 'Demand'})
          .assign(Time=df2['Value'], Demand_Time=df2['Value'] * df1['Value'])
          .reset_index(drop=True))
print(out)

# Output
   Origin  Destination    Demand        Time  Demand_Time
0      70          478  0.002779  135.974365     0.377873
1      70          479  0.001673  130.936752     0.219057
2      70          480  0.000427  111.191734     0.047479
3      70          481  0.001503   98.170746     0.147551
4      70          482  0.012150   88.257645     1.072330
5      70          483  0.004507  102.095566     0.460145
6      70          484  0.001871  103.585373     0.193808
7      70          485  0.006522  114.298431     0.745454
8      70          486  0.004786   97.331055     0.465826
9      70          487  0.026566   85.754776     2.278161
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the request correctly I would use a combination of pandas and numby to get the results you want in a timely manner

```
import datetime
import numpy as np

df_1_data = [[70, 478, 0.0027788935694843],
             [70, 479, 0.0016728754853829],
             [70, 480, 0.0004271405050531],
             [70, 481, 0.0015028485795482],
             [70, 482, 0.0121498983353376],
             [70, 483, 0.0045067127794027],
             [70, 484, 0.0018709792057052],
             [70, 485, 0.0065224897116422],
             [70, 486, 0.0047862790524959],
             [70, 487, 0.0265655759721994]]
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(df_1_data, columns=['Origin', 'Destination', 'Value'])
df_1 = df_1.set_index(df_1['Origin'].astype(str) + df_1['Destination'].astype(str))

# Replicating sample df2 (.read_csv from csv file 2)
df_2_data = [[70, 478, 135.9743652],
             [70, 479, 130.9367523],
             [70, 480, 111.1917343],
             [70, 481, 98.17074585],
             [70, 482, 88.25764465],
             [70, 483, 102.0955658],
             [70, 484, 103.5853729],
             [70, 485, 114.2984314],
             [70, 486, 97.33105469],
             [70, 487, 85.754776]]
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df_2_data, columns=['Origin', 'Destination', 'Value'])
df_2 = df_2.set_index(df_2['Origin'].astype(str) + df_2['Destination'].astype(str))

df_1.columns = [['Origin', 'Destination', 'Demand']]
df_2.columns = [['Origin', 'Destination', 'Time']]
df_merge = df_1.merge(df_2, how = 'inner')
df_merge['Demand_Time'] = df_merge['Time'].values / df_merge['Demand'].values
df_merge
```